# How to AND OR aws s3 copy statements with include

Tags: amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I'm copying between s3 buckets files from specific dates that are not sequence. 
In the example I'm copying from the 23, so I'd like to copy 15th, 19, and 23rd.

> aws s3 --region eu-central-1 --profile LOCALPROFILE cp
>   s3://SRC
>   s3://DEST --recursive
>   --exclude "*" --include "*2016-01-23*"

This source mentions using sequences http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/
 for include.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is it what you've asked in the title -- that is, how to specify multiple `include` conditions?

Comment: Yes, how to use include to copy from files with 23 OR 15 OR 19. That is is to say copy 2016-01-19 and 2016-23 and 2016-01-15 but **not** 2016-01-20, 2016-01-21, 2016-01-17

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears that you are asking how to copy multiple files/paths in one command.

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) allows multiple `--include` specifications, eg:

```
aws s3 cp s3://SRC s3://DEST --recursive --exclude "*" --include "2016-01-15/*" --include "2016-01-19/*" --include "2016-01-23/*"
```

The first `--exclude` says to exclude all files, then the subsequent `--include` parameters add paths to be included in the copy.

**See:** [Use of Exclude and Include Filters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters) in the documentation.

Comment: I have to do a similar thing - but I have way too many strings for `--include`. Is there a neater way to accomplish this? I have the strings in a .txt file.

Comment: You could call a separate `aws s3 cp` command for each directory you wish to copy.